# Change week day names on specific locale

Tags: settings, locale

Where Android stores strings like week day names, months, etc for each locale?
I dug into SettingsUI, framework-res, but didn't find anything related into res/values/arrays.xml or strings.xml. Could it be into the linked odex file?
I'm using a modified by me LG stock Rom KK 4.4 on a G2

Answer (score 0):

Found /system/usr/icu/icudt51l.dat
http://site.icu-project.org
Need to tamper with that file

Comment: followed this guide, profit https://code.google.com/archive/p/khmeriphone/wikis/How_to_Modify_ICU_dat.wiki